# Azure Search SearchParameters Object reference not set to an instance of an object error

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-cognitive-search

I am trying to add search fields to my Azure Search query (see below instantiation of the SearchParameters object).

```
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        ISearchIndexClient indexClient = CreateSearchIndexClient();
        try
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation($"Starting StartAsync");
            SearchParameters searchParameters = new SearchParameters();
            searchParameters.SearchFields.Add("StoreNumber");
            searchParameters.SearchFields.Add("StoreName");
            Trace.TraceInformation($"Finished adding search fields");
           // Trace.TraceInformation($"Search Parameters added = {searchParameters.SearchFields.Count}");

            DocumentSearchResult results = await indexClient.Documents.SearchAsync(searchText, searchParameters);
            Trace.TraceInformation($"results obtained");

            List<SearchHit> searchHits = results.Results.Select(r => ResultMapper.ToSearchHit(r)).ToList();
            Trace.TraceInformation($"search hits {searchHits.Count}");
            await SendResultsOfSearch(context, results);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError($"Exception {ex.ToString()}");
        }
    }
```

For some reason it's throwing the following exception but I have no idea why?

```
2018-09-03T00:47:39  PID[3268] Information Starting StartAsync
2018-09-03T00:47:39  PID[3268] Error       Exception System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at LuisBot.Dialogs.SearchRBMDialog.<StartAsync>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\Users\jmatson\Downloads\retail-info-bot-v2-src\Dialogs\SearchRBMDialog.cs:line 32
```

The code compiles fine? And there are no constructor arguments required as far as I know.

Comment: Can you clarify which line in StartAsync is line 32 (since that's what appears in the exception stack trace)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SearchFields` is not initialized by the `SearchParameters` constructor (see the source code [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/psSdkJson6/src/SDKs/Search/DataPlane/Microsoft.Azure.Search.Data/Customizations/Documents/Models/SearchParameters.cs)), so calling `Add` on it will result in `NullReferenceException`. It's of type `IList`, so the easiest way to initialize it is by assigning an array to it, like this:

```
searchParameters.SearchFields = new[] { "StoreNumber", "StoreName" };
```

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities (depending on your objects implementation):

Here:

```
SearchParameters searchParameters = new SearchParameters();
searchParameters.SearchFields.Add("StoreNumber");
searchParameters.SearchFields.Add("StoreName");
```

Is `SearchFields` a `List`? Was it initialized during `SearchParameters` construction? If not, in that case you can have a `NullReferenceException` when you add items to something non instantiated.

Or here:

```
List<SearchHit> searchHits = results.Results.Select(r => ResultMapper.ToSearchHit(r)).ToList();
```

In your `results` object, are you sure that `Results` is instantiated? If not, `NullReferenceException`

To find which line throws the Exception, look at line 32 in your code (the line number is in your error log)